# unable to uprade marklogic data hub framework using gradle

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am trying to follow the recommendation to upgrade the DHF using gradle but I am running through an issue that I cannot het my head around.

The build succeeds but the redeployment fails
Any idea on how to fix this ?

note that the login info is provided properly in the gradle.properties

```
> Task :hubDeploySecurity FAILED
Task ':hubDeploySecurity' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Deploying app DHF with config dirs: [/src/main/hub-internal-config, /src/main/ml-config]

Executing command [com.marklogic.appdeployer.command.security.DeployPrivilegesCommand] with sort order [5]
Will read and merge resource files in each config path before saving any resources
Processing files in directory: /src/main/hub-internal-config/security/privileges
Checking to see if Configuration Management API is available at: /manage/v3
Sending JSON POST request as user 'tkadmin' (who should have the 'manage-admin' and 'security' roles) to path: /manage/v3
Error occurred while sending POST request to /manage/v3; logging request body to assist with debugging: {}
Processing file: /src/main/hub-internal-config/security/privileges/dhf-internal-data-hub.json
Processing file: /src/main/hub-internal-config/security/privileges/dhf-internal-entities.json
Processing file: /src/main/hub-internal-config/security/privileges/dhf-internal-mappings.json
Processing file: /src/main/hub-internal-config/security/privileges/dhf-internal-trace-ui.json
Processing files in directory: /src/main/ml-config/security/privileges
Checking to see if Configuration Management API is available at: /manage/v3
Sending JSON POST request as user 'tkadmin' (who should have the 'manage-admin' and 'security' roles) to path: /manage/v3
Error occurred while sending POST request to /manage/v3; logging request body to assist with debugging: {}
Merging payloads that reference the same resource
Checking to see if Configuration Management API is available at: /manage/v3
Sending JSON POST request as user 'tkadmin' (who should have the 'manage-admin' and 'security' roles) to path: /manage/v3
Error occurred while sending POST request to /manage/v3; logging request body to assist with debugging: {}
Checking for existence of resource: dhf-internal-data-hub
Sending XML GET request as user 'tkadmin' (who should have the 'manage-admin' and 'security' roles) to path: /manage/v2/privileges
Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":   {"statusCode":401,
   "status":"Unauthorized",
   "message":"401 Unauthorized"
  }
}
:hubDeploySecurity (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.01 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hubDeploySecurity'.
> 401 Unauthorized: [{"errorResponse":   {"statusCode":401,
     "status":"Unauthorized",
     "message":"401 Unauthorized"
    }
  }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have followed the DHF upgrade matrix:

https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/upgrade.html

You probably ran the Gradle with an incorrect Admin interface & Security user. As such, the `hubUpdate` REST API requests will fail.

Try below see if it works:

> Step 2

```
gradle hubUpdate -i -PmlUsername=admin -PmlPassword={admin-password} -Penvironment={env-name}
```

> Step 4

```
gradle mlRedeploy -i -PmlUsername=admin -PmlPassword={admin-password} -Penvironment={env-name}
```